# Spring add some beans to service context in Runtime

Tags: java, spring, servlets, initialization, javabeans

I am creating spring dispatcherServlet and set his servlet context this way:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;


import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class MyDispatcherBean implements InitializingBean {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

    private final String someContext = "some.xml";

    private ServletContext servletContext;


    public void execute(/* Do some code..*/) throws IOException {

        /*
        Do some code..
        */
        try {
            dispatcherServlet.service(/* ...*/);
        } catch (ServletException e) {

        }

    }

    public WebApplicationContext getServiceContext() {
        return dispatcherServlet.getWebApplicationContext();
    }
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7492692694742330997L;

            @Override
            protected WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext() {
                WebApplicationContext wac = createWebApplicationContext(applicationContext);
                if (wac == null) {
                    wac = super.initWebApplicationContext();
                }
                return wac;
            }

        };

        dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation(someContext);
        dispatcherServlet.init(new DelegatingServletConfig());
    }

    private class DelegatingServletConfig implements ServletConfig {

        public String getServletName() {
            return "myDispatcher";
        }

        public ServletContext getServletContext() {
            return MyDispatcherBean.this.servletContext;
        }

        public String getInitParameter(String paramName) {
            return null;
        }

        public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
            return Collections.enumeration(new HashSet<String>());
        }
    }

}
```

And i create that bean this way:

```
<bean id="myDispatcher" class="some.package.MyDispatcherBean " />
```

Then in any place in my code can exist any numbers of beans with code that get "myDispatcher" bean and add some beans in Runtime to servlet context of DispatcherServlet:

```
public class ContextAdder implements InitializingBean {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public String classPathToContext;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {


        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = applicationContext.getBean("myDispatcher",DispatcherServlet.class);
        XmlWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = (XmlWebApplicationContext) dispatcherServlet.getWebApplicationContext();
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((DefaultListableBeanFactory) webApplicationContext.getBeanFactory());
        xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource(classPathToContext));

    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public String getClassPathToContext() {
        return classPathToContext;
    }

    public void setClassPathToContext(String classPathToContext) {
        this.classPathToContext = classPathToContext;
    }
}
```

These beans are created this way:

```
<bean id="adder1" class="stargate.sg_1.ContextAdder" depends-on="myDispatcher">
        <property name="classPathToContext" value="Optimus.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="adder2" class="stargate.atlantida.ContextAdder" depends-on="myDispatcher">
        <property name="classPathToContext" value="StarShip.xml" />
</bean>
```

In finally I expect behaviour: each ContextAdder bean add new beans to servlet context of dispatcherServlet in myDispatcher bean.

**But i am afraid of some moments:**

1. Is it only one decision of this problem?
2. Is it the best one?
3. Each time when i add new bean to servletContext of DispatcherServlet - will it invoke refresh of ServletContext or even ApplicationContext? If it is true - does it have influence on performance?
4. Is all lifecycles is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a better approach, but will leave it to you to decide.

With your approach (implements InitializingBean) you are invoking your bean creation code after the bean definitions phase has completed and **after** the beans are being constructed.  Your bean definition phase is very simple (just create "myDispatcher").

I would recommend that you create/load all your bean definitions during the bean definition phase.  One way to achieve this is to instead hook into the BeanFactory post processor (implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor).  At this phase Spring lets you modify existing bean definitions and more importantly for you add further bean definitions.  Now when you leave this phase, all beans will then be created in one phase.  The approach is very natural: bean definitions are created => beans are created and wired => Done.

```
public class ContextAdder implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory)
        throws BeansException {

    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((BeanDefinitionRegistry)factory);

    // I)  LOAD BY PATTERN MATCHING
    //PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(factory.getBeanClassLoader());
    //for (Resource resource : resourceResolver.getResources("com/.../*.xml"))
    //reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

    // II)  LOAD A SINGLE FILE AT A TIME
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("com/../Optimus.xml""));
    .....
}
```

Perhaps you can adopt this concept to your unique requirement.

Comment: If i add beans to servlet context (not in application context) in postProcessBeanFactory will it be in one phase?

Comment: Yes.  Each context has an opportunity to participate in a BeanFactoryPostProcessor during the definition phase.

Comment: When I create ContextAdder bean in ApplicationContext - ServletContext is not initialized. Should I create ContextAdder bean in started servlet context (servlet context of dispatcher servlet)?

Comment: do you use web.xml, or new approach: implements WebApplicationInitializer?  The servlet context should be started in one of those two ways and then you use loadBeanDefinitions.

Comment: i haven't access to web.xml.... :( and i create Dispatcher programmatically.   So is it possible to add beans to servlet context this way?

Comment: I mean - is there a way to invoke method like in BeanFactoryPostProcessor but for ServletContext of my dispacherServlet? As i understand, first Application Context is createn and then ServletContext... right?

Comment: I didn't realize you had no control over web.xml.  Can you instead create a class which implements WebApplicationInitializer?  I am not so sure how good to make it with your programmatic approach.  But Spring will allow all contexts to get a BeanFactoryPostProcessor at some point.

Comment: i don't have control over web.xml because i use some kind of portal and... i don't want to change the source of it. Yes, i can create WebApplicationInitializer programaticly - does it help me?

Comment: WebApplicationInitializer has method onStartup with argument ServletContext container. I think it will invoke some kind of refresh or reinit if i add some beans to this context? Is in it? http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Comment: Yes.  I use it to create my contexts (including servlet), and plug into the refresh events that Spring provides (including BeanFactoryPostProcessor) using it.

Comment: If i have 100 ContextAdder bean - it will call method refresh 100 times?hmm. As i can see in Spring Doc. StartUp method call before Spring ApplicationCotnext is initialized (no beans) here... it is bad for me because I can't get all ContextAdders.......

Comment: If you add the contextadder beans during the same bean definition phase, then you only get 1 refresh event at the end.

Comment: As i can see in Spring Doc. StartUp method call before Spring ApplicationCotnext is initialized (no beans) here... it is bad for me because I can't get all ContextAdders...... This way i can't get all ContextAdders bean to know all cotexts and add it it servlet context....

Comment: Without knowing all your structure, I can't help.  I use startUp() to create both the root and servlet context, and then programmatically add whatever other bean are required to those contexts (using java config).  I don't understand where your adders are defined, and detected, and why they can't be added in one phase after creating the context... sorry.

Comment: Wow i think you have already gave me the answer... I can use  resourceResolver.getResources("com/.../*.xml") to get all resouce by Pattern.... Thank you :) Rigth? If i define a lot of context with controller with name ***bla-bla.xml then i can add it to servletContext when i create dispatcherServlet? Right?:D Thank for your quick answer.

Comment: Yes, that was part of my confusion.  If you have a pattern, use it - it all happens in one phase.  If you didn't have a pattern, how could you know all your beans?  So now it is solved!

Comment: But now I know smth new about  WebApplicationInitializer without web.xml. Great thanks!